# How to make x and y coordinates as variables when adding point to ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am adding a point to a ggplot, how can I make the x and y coordinates as variables? I tried this code, but it does not work

```
func <- function(data){

  meanx <- mean(data[,1])
  meany <- mean(data[,2])

  p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = data[,1], y = data[,2]))
  p + 
  geom_point(size = 5, shape = 19, color = "#00FF00",
         aes(x = meanx, y = meany))

}

func(iris)
```

I have the following error:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'meanx' not found
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: take a look at `aes_string`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution would be to replace

```
geom_point(size = 5, shape = 19, color = "#00FF00", aes(x = meanx, y = meany))
```

with

```
annotate("point",size = 5, shape = 19, color = "#00FF00", x = meanx, y = meany)
```

Answer (score 3):

The error message is due to `meanx` and `meany` not being part of the data frame `data` which is specified as value of the parameter `data` in the `ggplot` function.

It will work if you add the argument `data = data.frame(meanx, meany)` to `geom_point`.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `aes_string`, like Justing says. This does exactly what you ask, use a string to assign aesthetics. However, it is better to, as Sven suggested, to just put the meanx and meany into a data.frame.